# Query information about my app's user in twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I want to query information about my app's user Info (name, id...)
In twitter (**PHP**).
What I want to know how I can reuse the token credentials of user???
I have done that but with my Twitter session. It means I must login with my twitter account, after that I can query information about my app's user (That's not correct!!!!!).

Answer (score 2):

Please read this, this will be useful for your query :- 
http://mikerogers.io/2013/02/25/how-use-twitter-oauth-1-1-javascriptjquery.html